# Return to MainActivity from another activity with error message

Tags: android, android-activity

I am a bit new in android and I want to return to main activity from current activity with error message in dialog box.

I have written a script which make a call to rest api and if there is no data or error from response then i want to return to main activity with that error in dialog box.

Here is what i am doing

```
txtScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });

     private void selectImage(){
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                "Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                            SELECT_FILE);


   } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }
    }


private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        byte[] b;

        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        String fileName =  File.separator + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
        filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + fileName;
        System.out.println(filePath);
        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        /*FileInputStream fis = null;
        try{
            fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        b = bytes.toByteArray();
        encode_string = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(encode_string);
        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            obj =  new JSONObject();
            obj.put("image",encode_string);
            obj.put("api_key",API_SECRET);
            System.out.println(obj.toString());
        }catch (Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

       new Image().execute();
        //new LongRunningGetIO().execute();

        //ivImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }
```

This function is In Image class

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void r) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if(responseBody == "Api key does not found/match"){
                //here i want to return to main activity with error
            }else {

                byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(encode_string.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                //System.out.println(imageAsBytes);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("filePath", imageAsBytes);
                //intent.putExtra("data", text);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
```

Any idea thanks in advance

Comment: As with your ViewActivity gets an extra "filePath" you can pass your MainActivity an extra "errorMessage".

Comment: start MainActivity by setting error data using Intent.putExtra.

Comment: start your current activity using `startActivityForResult` from mainactivity (in case if this activity is called from mainactivity), or when you return to mainactiivity send data with it (if you are returning from other activity to mainactivity,keep in mind to check nullpointer at `getIntent().getString("")`).

Answer (score 1):

use [startActivityForResults](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example) for passing value from current activity to previous activity

**call Activity**

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,CurrentActivity.class);  
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

**Handle result on MainActivity**

```
@Override  
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
       {  
                 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
                  // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
                   if(requestCode==2)  
                         {  
                            String error=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");   
                           //display error
                         }  
     }
```

**Async**

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void r) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if(responseBody == "Api key does not found/match"){

               Intent intent=new Intent();  
                    intent.putExtra("Error",message);  
                    setResult(2,intent);  
                    finish();
            }else {

                byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(encode_string.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                //System.out.println(imageAsBytes);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("filePath", imageAsBytes);
                //intent.putExtra("data", text);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
```

Comment: where should i write this line of code

Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,CurrentActivity.class);  
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

Comment: @HassanShahbaz you are call current activity from main activty right so just call currentactivity like this

Comment: so instead of startactivity use startactivityforresult.

Comment: @ KDeogharkar Actually on button click camera opens and when picture is captured there is a button named Save when click on that button it hit an api and then return response on that response i want to return to that activity which contain this fragment which have button for taking picture...
I have updated my questoin as well